# How to convert a string containing a number into its binary representation?

Tags: bash

I'm retrieving the size of a file with the following command:

```
du -b foo.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

Let's say this outputs `1337`.

How can I convert the number in this string into it's binary representation as a (e.g.) 4-byte integer (like `atoi` in C) and write that data to a file?

It would be a nice to have to be able to specify endianess.

*If anyone knows some good tags for this question, please feel free to add them.*

Comment: There are no 4-byte integers in bash that you csn access. A binary representation of a number is a string of bits, e.g characters `'0'` and `'1'`. Is this what you want? Why do you need a converted value? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Or you can get hex representation of the number.

Comment: I know I can't handle binary data in bash, that's why I said I want to write it to a file. I need that file to `dd` it to a special position in a bootloader for an ARM chip. So no, I don't mean a string of `0`'s and `1`'s (or hex), but *binary data*.

Comment: I have to admit that *binary representation* is a bit ambiguous. Maybe I should change the title of the question to *How to simulate atoi() in bash?*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bash:

```
number=1234

printf -v t '%08x' "$number"
# This form may not be necessary:
# printf -v t '%08x' "$(( number & 0xFFFFFFFF ))"
l=${#t}

# Little endian format.
hex_le="\\x${t:l-2:2}\\x${t:l-4:2}\\x${t:l-6:2}\\x${t:l-8:2}"
printf "$hex_le" > file

# Big endian format.
hex_be="\\x${t:l-8:2}\\x${t:l-6:2}\\x${t:l-4:2}\\x${t:l-2:2}"
printf "$hex_be" > file
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know there is a `printf` util. That will come in handy in so many situations. I simplified the format string a bit. Great answer!

Comment: Thanks, you too ;) I added two more checks for the length of the hex string, so that now even numbers that can't be represented in 4 bytes are correctly cut off.

Comment: You mean `${t:l-2}`? It's always equivalent to `${t:l-2:2}` as it's in the end of the string. But that doesn't really give difference in anyway.

Comment: Sorry brain fail. You are right of course. Like this it's more symmetrical now ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
xxd -b
```

[quoted manpage :](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html) 
xxd creates a hex dump of a given file or standard input. It can also convert a hex dump back to its original binary form. Like uuencode(1) and uudecode(1) it allows the transmission of binary data in a `mail-safe' ASCII representation, but has the advantage of decoding to standard output. Moreover, it can be used to perform binary file patching.

The -b option switches to bits dump, rather than hexdump. This option writes octets as eight digits "1"s and "0"s instead of a normal hexacecimal dump. Each line is preceded by a line number in hexadecimal and followed by an ascii (or ebcdic) representation. The command line switches -r, -p, -i do not work with this mode.